# Guys is there any way to check Token mint date

Tags: solana-program

** How to check the launch/mint date of tokens(SPL) created on solana network?***is there any way to check on any SOLANA explorer ?*

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: imports

```
const {
  Connection,
  PublicKey,
  clusterApiUrl
} = require("@solana/web3.js");
const moment = require('moment');
```

Step 2: function

```
const firstTimestamp = async () => {

  const mintID = new PublicKey("BrsE4BdXip29GLE8DqxqhzAiDVEW7LYzxWAabdfLLb3f");
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"));
  const txList = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(mintID, {});
  const unixTime = txList[txList.length-1].blockTime;
  const oldestTxTimestamp = moment.unix(unixTime).format("MM/DD/YYYY,h:mm:ss a")
  console.log(oldestTxTimestamp);
  return oldestTxTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this requires you to loop through all the tx to find the first one  :`(

Comment: it doesn't work if you have more than 1000 transaction, because getSignaturesForAddress return the last 1000 transactions by default. 
you can change this limit but it's between 1 and 1000

Answer (score 1):

You may use some service providing access to indexed db like dune.com and make a query like this.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM solana.account_activity
WHERE
    address = {{ address }}
ORDER BY
  block_time
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).